# Is it possible to request for aggregate and detailed data in the same DataReadRequest?

Tags: android, google-fit

I'm using Google fit API to store and read data in an android app.

This request is working:

```
DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED, DataType.AGGREGATE_CALORIES_EXPENDED)
            .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_DISTANCE_DELTA)
            .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_SPEED, DataType.AGGREGATE_SPEED_SUMMARY)
            .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE, DataType.AGGREGATE_LOCATION_BOUNDING_BOX)
            .bucketBySession(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .enableServerQueries()
            .build();
```

But I would like to request for the detailed location points instead of aggregating them into a bounding box:

```
DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED, DataType.AGGREGATE_CALORIES_EXPENDED)
            .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_DISTANCE_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_DISTANCE_DELTA)
            .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_SPEED, DataType.AGGREGATE_SPEED_SUMMARY)
            .read(DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE)
            .bucketBySession(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .enableServerQueries()
            .build();
```

Is this request supposed to work? Cause I'm not getting datasets for the `TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE` requested.

Comment: did you finally find a solution for this???